# CakePHP - Merge two Table in One

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a problem, i have two models they are "Clientes" and "Residencias" (it's in portuguese).

My problem is.. im trying to link these two in just one...i created a new table with "cliente_id" and "residencia_id"...

the output using the relation $belongsTo is like that...

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'bd' => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'cliente_id' => null,
            'residencia_id' => 2
        ),
        'Cliente' => array(),
        'Residencia' => array(
            'id' => 2
            'nome'  => 'aaa',
            'telefone'  => '333'
        )
    ),
    1 => array(
        'bd' => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'cliente_id' => 1,
            'residencia_id' null
        ),
        'Cliente' => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'nome' => 'bbb',
            'telefone' => '666'
        ),
        'Residencia' => array()
    )
)
```

get it??

i wanna do this:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'bd' => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'cliente_id' => null,
            'residencia_id' => 2
        ),
        'Result' => array(
            'id' => 2
            'nome'  => 'aaa',
            'telefone'  => '333'
        )
    ),
    1 => array(
        'bd' => array(
            'id' => 2,
            'cliente_id' => 1,
            'residencia_id' null
        ),
        'Result' => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'nome' => 'bbb',
            'telefone' => '666'
        )
    )
)
```

get it?? i wanna do this in the model and Paginate that...someone can help me?? i didnt find answer for that...i dont know how...

thank you

Comment: As far as I understand your requirements, this is not a typical DB association that can be automatically created for you from any database using SQL. Therefore you will need to add the proper logic in your model that will parse and format the results as you want them depending on whether client or residence is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an afterFind callback in the model you are querying that would modify the result and return it in the format you want. It could look something like this:

```
    public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
    if ($this->findQueryType == 'count' || !$primary) {
        return parent::afterFind($results, $primary);
    }

    foreach ($results as $k => $result) {
        if (!empty($result['Cliente'])) {
            $id = $result['Cliente']['id'];
            $nome = $result['Cliente']['nome'];
            $telefone = $result['Cliente']['telefone'];
        } else if (!empty($result['Residencia'])) {
            $id = $result['Residencia']['id'];
            $nome = $result['Residencia']['nome'];
            $telefone = $result['Residencia']['telefone'];
        }

        $results[$k]['Result'] = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'nome' => $nome,
            'telefone' => $telefone
        );
        unset($results[$k]['Cliente']);
        unset($results[$k]['Residencia']);
        continue;
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Naiaretti...but if i do this i cant use the CakePHP Paginator =/ i need to use it...

Comment: In that case, you will need to leave the result array as it is and wrap your view paginator tags in 2 separate conditions. So, depending which array is not empty, paginate the right model.

`<tr>
  <td><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Cliente.nome', ucwords(__('nome'))); ?></td>
</tr>
else {... paginate Residencia fields ...}`